# Singular points in ODE's

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

It is generally said we need to bring an ODE to the form:

$$ y'' +P(x)y' + Q(x)y = 0$$

And then check where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are not analytic to determine singular points. My question is **why?** Why do we check it only after dividing the equation and getting $y''$ to "stand alone". What's the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Because the usual existence theorems are only formulated for explicit ODE.

It is a relatively easy consequence of the Picard-Lindelöf-Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem(s) that
$$
y^{(n)}(x)+a_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)}(x)+...+a_0(x)y(x)=r(x)
$$
has solutions with domain $I$ whenever the coefficients and right side are continuous on $I$.

That the DE is singular at some point does not necessarily mean that any solution has to be singular there, only that the examination of the point requires extended means. But usually the family of solutions shows singular behavior at singular points, either generally diverging or converging to some proper subset of the state space (remember, a regular DE is defined on all of the state space).